# Django: best way to convert data from model to view

Tags: python, django

My django app displays the objects from database in table view. The problem is that these objects (models) are pretty complex: the have 50+ fields. Nearly for each field I have to do some formatting:

- conver phone numbers from int 71234567689 to "+7 (123) 456789"
- display long prices with spaces: "7 000 000" instead of "7000000"
- construct full address from several fields like "street", "house" and so on (logic if pretty complex with several if-else-s)
- and so on

Django templating language has several useful tags for simple cases but I guess is not suitable in general case (like mine) for serious formatting.

Create the @property-s in model class is also not an option because the question is about rendering and is not related to model.

So I guess I should do my conversions in view: create dict for each obj, fill with converted data and pass to template.

But! The model has a lot of fields and I don't want to copy them all :) Moreover, it would be great to preserve model structure to use it in django template (say, regroup) and query set laziness.

**So the greatest way would be to instruct django "how to render". Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Django Rest Framework`, then you can simply use `serializers`. But I don't think that is a case. What you want to accomplish seems very similar to the role of django `forms`, but as such they are only used (conventionally) for saving/updating models i.e. POST requests. Now either you can define a new class for filtering/rendering and use that in your view or just go ahead and use django forms which would automatically provide basic cleaning for different fields.

Comment: I dont' use djang-rest-framework and I think it's kinda overkill. UI is read-only so I need only model-to-view conversion.

Forms also doesn't fit: several conversions are pretty complex: take that field, check if satisfies the condition, otherwise check that field, etc. etc. etc.

I guess I will create a standalone class and iterate over query set to convert models to this class.

But I still don't like it :(

Comment: Sure, just create a renderer class, you may inherit from form base class if you want to use some inbuilt functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Django rest framework

examples from the doc (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)

```
class Color(object):
    """
    A color represented in the RGB colorspace.
    """
    def __init__(self, red, green, blue):
        assert(red >= 0 and green >= 0 and blue >= 0)
        assert(red < 256 and green < 256 and blue < 256)
        self.red, self.green, self.blue = red, green, blue

class ColorField(serializers.Field):
    """
    Color objects are serialized into 'rgb(#, #, #)' notation.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return "rgb(%d, %d, %d)" % (obj.red, obj.green, obj.blue)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.strip('rgb(').rstrip(')')
        red, green, blue = [int(col) for col in data.split(',')]
        return Color(red, green, blue)
```

after you define your custom serializers/Field.
You only need to dictate which serializer to use to represent your data